# Handle element not found Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I used to create functions in controllers like this with Laravel 5.8 and I was able to handle when the item was not found redirecting the user to the index page with an error notification.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $template = Template::find($id);
    if ($template) {
        return view('admin.templates.edit', compact(['template']));
    }
    $this->setNotifications('error', 'Not found');

    return redirect()->route('admin.templates.index');
}
```

Now with Laravel 6 the function declaration has changed and if the item is not found, it displays the default not found page directly, ignoring the code in the function and I'm not able handle the not found error as I used to do.

```
public function edit(Template $template)
{
    if ($template) {
         return view('admin.templates.edit', compact(['template']));
    }
    $this->setNotifications('error', 'Not found');

    return redirect()->route('admin.templates.index');
}
```

Is there a way to use the Laravel 6 way and handle what happens when the item is not found at the same time?

Comment: You can still change controller code of edit function and implement it the same way as in 5.8. Pay attention that in routes file you have to change it in order to accept the edit with the `$id` and the `$request`

Comment: @PedroCosta In fact I'm using `Route::resource` and it works with both, `$id` and `Template $template`. By the way `Request $request` variable is optional so I prefer to use `request()`.